# Поиск текста с учетом звучания на русском и английском языках

Tags: elasticsearch, индексация, полнотекстовый-поиск, lucene

Какими средствами лучше всего организовать индексирование и поиск русских слов, которые являются записью английской транскрипции? Например, слово `vision` в русском варианте будет записано как `вижн` или `вижен`, но значение сути не меняется. Поиск, соответственно, должен быть произведен как по `vision` так и по `вижн` без потери результатов на выходе. 
Soundex и Metaphone, на сколько я понимаю, работают строго в одном языке без скрещиваний.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мне кажется, в большинстве случаев, будет достаточно [функционала синонимов](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.0/analysis-synonym-tokenfilter.html). База данных, скорее всего, имеет определенную тематическую направленность, например медицина или электротехника. И чтобы настроить поиск с учетом транслита/звучания слов на разных языках достаточно заполнить 500-1000 синонимов. Но использовать анализатор с фильтром типа synonym не для индексации, а для анализа поискового запроса.

Синонимы лучше вынести в отдельный файл, а не хранить в настройках.

```js
{
    "index" : {
        "analysis" : {
            "analyzer" : {
                "synonym" : {
                    "tokenizer" : "whitespace",
                "filter" : ["synonym"]
            }
        },
        "filter" : {
                "synonym" : {
                    "type" : "synonym",
                "synonyms_path" : "analysis/synonym.txt"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Пример содержимого файла synonym.txt:

**vision, вижн, вижен**

---

Если этого недостаточно, то получаем очень сложную задачу.

Если дело ограничивается транслитом, то смотреть в сторону плагина [ICU Transform Token Filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/2.4/analysis-icu-transform.html)
Если нет, и нужно **vision, вижн, вижен** для всех возможных слов, то смотреть в сторону машинного обучения. Это решение [Rosette for Elasticsearch](https://www.rosette.com/elastic/), видимо платное.

Полезные ссылки.

- [Обсуждение данной темы](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/topic/62375)
- [Rosette name translator](http://www.basistech.com/text-analytics/rosette/name-translator/) - есть
  поддержка русского языка

Soundex и Metaphone - это фонетические алгоритмы, работают, как вы написали, в одном языке. Это не то, что вам нужно.

Comment: Спасибо за ссылки, как раз в точку! Скорее всего придется решить задачу через синонимы, либо Soundex/Metaphone как посоветовали здесь: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30843475/phonetic-search-for-indian-languages

Comment: Я бы тоже не стал заморачиваться. Синонимы прекрасно работают. Но у них есть существенный минус -  это такая глобальная настройка, нельзя задать синонимы для определенного поля или группы полей.